# Postgres error during test data insert script

Tags: postgresql

I spun up a separate Postsgres server and was able to connect to it from my local computer. I left a script running overnight that was supposed to insert 10_000_000 records into several tables (user, user_preferences, user_coordinates, etc).

I waited for the first 1_000_000 records to be inserted before going to bed. This morning, I woke up to the following error:

```
FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command
```

What exactly does this error mean? Obviously I am the admin and obviously I didn't issue a command. Network connectivity issue?

Comment: Was that the only thing?  Usually this message is accompanied with more info than just that.  Look in the db log to see if it has more info, either in the same message or in adjacent messages.

Comment: @jjanes The problem was that my freshly spun up Postgres dev server got brute forced into by a ransomware attacker. A clean OS install (and a firewall) fixed this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error may be caused by a memory or CPU limitation, an idle connection timeout, going over the maximum number of connections, an administrator's manual termination, or any combination of these factors. Examine the **pg_log/postgresql.log** file's server logs for any information on the termination time in order to conduct an investigation. Long-running transaction-related problems may be resolved by modifying the script to log specific progress and dividing insertions into smaller batches.
Hope it's helpful :)